# unable to make webform Structure like as shown in image in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

[image: Structure of Web form]

as i am trying from many days i am unable to build this type of dynamic web form using asp.new with c# please anybody can help me it will be great help to me ... please please

Add Sub Steps adds new text box and add more step adds main Step with same sub step button and remove button removes that particular text box and related text box with it..
after completing all it need to submit in database . but i have problem in creating Dynamic form like this in tree view.

Comment: what have your tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **2 nested repeaters**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="StepRep" runat="server" OnItemCommand="StepRep_ItemCommand" 
    onitemdatabound="StepRep_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                </td>
                <td>
                    %
                </td>
                <td>
                    Remove
                </td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="Step<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 %>">
            <td align=right>
                Step
                <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align=right>
                <asp:TextBox ID="NameBox" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Columns="50" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="RatioBox" Text='<%# Eval("Ratio") %>' Columns="5" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveLink" runat="server" Text="X" CommandName="StepRemove" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <asp:Repeater ID="SubStepRep" runat="server" OnItemCommand="SubStepRep_ItemCommand" onitemdatabound="SubStepRep_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="SubTr" runat="server">
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td align=right>
                        Sub Step
                        <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
                    </td>
                    <td align=right>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="SubNameBox" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' Columns="35" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td align=right>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="SubRatioBox" Text='<%# Eval("Ratio") %>' Columns="5" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SubRemoveLink" runat="server" Text="X" CommandName="SubStepRemove" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <tr class="Step<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 %>">
            <td colspan="2">
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:Button ID="SubAddButton" runat="server" Text="add sub steps" CommandName="SubStepAdd" />
            </td>
                <td colspan="2">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TotalRatioBox" Columns="5" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="StepAddButton" runat="server" Text="add more steps" CommandName="StepAdd" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and Simple **CSS** like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.Table1
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.Table1 td
    {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    tr.Step0
    {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    tr.Step1
    {
        background: #ddd;
    }
</style>
```

**And Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class RepeaterPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            readForm();
        }else {
            var step1 = new StepItem();
            step1.SubSteps= new List<SubStepItem>();
            step1.SubSteps.Add(new SubStepItem());

            var Steps = new List<StepItem>();
            Steps.Add(step1);

            StoredList = Steps;

            bindRepeater();
        }
    }

    private void bindRepeater()
    {
        StepRep.DataSource = StoredList;
        StepRep.DataBind();
    }

    private List<StepItem> StoredList
    {
        get
        {
            var o = ViewState["StoredList"];
            if (o == null) return new List<StepItem>();
            return (List<StepItem>)o;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["StoredList"] = value;
        }
    }

    private void readForm()
    {
        var steps = new List<StepItem>();
        foreach (RepeaterItem RI in StepRep.Items)
        {
            var step = new StepItem();
            step.Name = ((TextBox)RI.FindControl("NameBox")).Text;
            step.Ratio = Double.Parse(((TextBox)RI.FindControl("RatioBox")).Text);
            step.SubSteps = new List<SubStepItem>(); 

            var SubRep= (Repeater)RI.FindControl("SubStepRep");
            foreach (RepeaterItem SubRI in SubRep.Items)
            {
                var subStep = new SubStepItem();
                subStep.Name = ((TextBox)SubRI.FindControl("SubNameBox")).Text;
                subStep.Ratio = Double.Parse(((TextBox)SubRI.FindControl("SubRatioBox")).Text);
                step.SubSteps.Add(subStep);
            }
            steps.Add(step);
        }
        StoredList = steps;
    }

    protected void StepRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            var Step = (StepItem)e.Item.DataItem;

            Repeater SubRep = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("SubStepRep");
            SubRep.DataSource = Step.SubSteps;
            SubRep.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void SubStepRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            var StepRepItem = (RepeaterItem)e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer;
            var tr = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("SubTr");
            tr.Attributes.Add("class",  "Step" + (StepRepItem .ItemIndex % 2 ) );
        }
    }

    protected void StepRep_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var steps = StoredList;
        if(e.CommandName =="StepAdd") {
            steps.Add(new StepItem() ) ;
            StoredList = steps;
            bindRepeater();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "StepRemove")
        {
            steps.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
            StoredList = steps;
            bindRepeater();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "SubStepAdd")
        {
            steps[e.Item.ItemIndex].SubSteps.Add(new SubStepItem());
            StoredList = steps;
            bindRepeater();
        }

    }

    protected void SubStepRep_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        var StepRepItem = (RepeaterItem)e.Item.NamingContainer.NamingContainer ;  

        var steps = StoredList;

        if (e.CommandName == "SubStepRemove")
        {
            steps[StepRepItem.ItemIndex].SubSteps.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);

            StoredList = steps;
            bindRepeater();
        }
    }

}

[Serializable]
public class StepItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Ratio { get; set; }
    public List<SubStepItem> SubSteps { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SubStepItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Ratio { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there possibility of validation of 100% at last while submitting ?

Comment: you can add one custom validator and implement its server-side validation and also client-side valdiation if you need to

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark as answer

Comment: could u tell me y i cannot access TextBox Directly and put value in it Like  
TotalRatioBox.text = "Any Value"

Comment: because it is part of the repeater footer, to access it check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701412/how-to-find-controls-in-a-repeater-header-or-footer or take it out of the footer template and access it directly (and do the same with header in that case)

Comment: i am Trying this but not working 
((Label)StepRep.Controls[StepRep.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("TotalRatio")).Text = total.ToString();

Comment: are you using the wrong id and type ? should it be : ((TextBox)StepRep.Controls[StepRep.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("TotalRatioBox")).Text = total.ToString()

Comment: Thanks i got my answer .. :) actually you right , and i made little change i have added Label instead of Textbox.