# C# Get first repeater item column value to use on HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to get a column value of the first element on a repeater, and use it on the repeater's HeaderTemplate. After searching and trying many ways of achieving this through intellisense, I gave up and decided to post this question here.

My code is as follows:

*Frontend*

```
<asp:Repeater ID="states" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h1>Stage: <asp:Literal ID="stageName" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h1>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StateName") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

*Backend*

```
protected void BindStageStates()
     {
       List<StagesStatesModel> statesList = App.Services.Stages.StagesService.GetStatesByStage(Page.DefaultApp, 1, Page.DefaultCultureId).Where(p => p.StateActive == true).ToList();
       states.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptStagesStatesDataBound);
       states.DataSource = statesList;
       states.DataBind();
     }

void rptStagesStatesDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
         {
             Literal stageName = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("stageName");
             stageName.Text = // Something to go here..
         }    
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i guess that you might bind `stageName` when bind first dataItem, not bind it in Header.

Comment: question is I only need stageName on the header, since it will be the same for all items in the repeater!

Answer (score 0):

Try OnItemCreated

```
protected void Repeater_OnItemCreated(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {    
          e.Item.FindControl(ctrl);
        }
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
          e.Item.FindControl(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

By:
[How to find controls in a repeater header or footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701412/how-to-find-controls-in-a-repeater-header-or-footer)