# adding imageurl to image element dynamically wont work

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, asp.net-webcontrol

so iam trying to add a image i have saved on my project in image folder. But it dosent work

```
DirectCast(Customer.Items(0).FindControl("imageControl"), Image).ImageUrl = "~/images/IMG_1287.JPG"
DirectCast(Customer.Items(0).FindControl("imageControl"),   Image).DataBind()
```

customer is the repeater html element the image element is in. I cant call the image element direct in the server code because the image element is inside a repeater element. So i have to use findcontrol method which works good. When i debugg the code i can se that it finds the right image element the problem is when i set the imageurl nothing seems to happen in the ui but i dont understand why can anybody help me please :)

```
<div>
<asp:Image ID="imageControl" Width="100%" Height="70%" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you are not trying access controls within repeater in correct manner , it should be like :

**If image is in header :**

```
DirectCast(Customer.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("imageControl"), Image).ImageUrl = "~/images/IMG_1287.JPG"
```

**If image is in footer**

```
DirectCast(Customer.Controls[Customer.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("imageControl"), Image).ImageUrl = "~/images/IMG_1287.JPG"
```

Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701422/1531476) for more details.

*PS : Are you using vb ? cause i have used C# syntax, if yes change accordingly.*